# Ephesians 2:2, which one comes first in the Calvinist view?

Tags: exegesis, reformed-theology, demons, spirit, ephesians

Ephesians 2:2 reads:

> in which you used to live when you followed the ways of this world and
>   of the ruler of the kingdom of the air, **the spirit who is now at work
>   in those who are disobedient**.

- A. Because the spirit is at work to some people, those people become
  disobedient.
- B. Because some people are disobedient, the spirit is at work in
  those people.

According to Calvinist, is A or B the correct one ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Calvin's commentary on Ephesians 2:2](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/calvin/calcom41.iv.iii.i.html) :

> We may now draw from it also this inference, that ungodly men have no excuse in being driven by Satan to commit all sorts of crimes. Whence comes it that they are subject to his tyranny, but because they are rebels against God? If none are the slaves of Satan, but those who have renounced the service, and refuse to yield to the authority, of God, let them blame themselves, for having so cruel a master.

Choice B. Those who refuse to yield to the authority of God become subject to the tyranny of Satan.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bradimus. I choose your answer as the accepted one.